# Feeding emma coverage to sonar

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm trying to feed sonar with emma results for a multimodule project

```
mvn sonar:sonar  -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis='true' -Dsonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=emma -Dsonar.emma.reportPath=target
```

For each module I get:

```
instrumentation path processed in 1798 ms
[146 class(es) instrumented, 19 resource(s) copied]
metadata merged into [<module>/target/coverage.em] {in 152 ms}
```

and later:

```
[INFO] [12:24:32.514] Sensor EmmaSensor...
[INFO] [12:24:32.514] Parse reports: <module>/target
[WARN] [12:24:32.514] No coverage (*.ec) file found in <module>/target
[INFO] [12:24:35.123] Sensor EmmaSensor done: 2609 ms
```

So I get 0% coverage in sonar
Why is it trying to find .ec files instead of .em files?

Sonar version is: 3.5.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you mentioned the Sonar version you use.

However I think that the parameter sonar.dynamicAnalysis should have the value of 'reuseReports' and not 'true'
Also make sure that the em files are existing under the target folder
For more information see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project 
and 
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Emma+Plugin

Comment: Hi, sonar version is 3.5.1. Reports do exist in every submodule target folder. I tried with reuseReports and I get same [WARN] [07:57:28.000] No coverage (*.ec) file found in <module>/target messages and still 0% coverage.